# SFML C++ union constructor is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill formed

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, sfml, unions

I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 hours but i cant. I am trying to learn c++ but i am stuck here. I don't know the problem. I was trying to create an object pool to use with my bullet objects so i could spawn and despawn them easily without memory leak. My source is as follows:

main.cpp

--the first error is in the constructor of the Bullet class and the update method of the BulletPool class.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "bullets.hpp"
#include "enemies.hpp"

BulletPool::BulletPool() { //no matching function for call to 'Bullet::Bullet()'
  // The first one is available.
  firstAvailable_ = &bullets_[0];

  // Each particle points to the next.
  for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE - 1; i++)
  {
    bullets_[i].setNext(&bullets_[i + 1]);
  }

  // The last one terminates the list.
  bullets_[POOL_SIZE - 1].setNext(NULL);
}


Bullet::Bullet(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, sf::Vector2f vel) { //  candidate expects 6 arguments, 0 provided
    onScreen_=true;
    inUse = true;
    state_.live.enemy_ = enemy;
    state_.live.velocity_ = vel;
    shape.setRadius(bullet_radius);
    shape.setOrigin(bullet_radius, bullet_radius);
    shape.setFillColor(color);
    shape.setPosition(pos);
}

void Bullet::update(sf::Vector2f screen) {
    shape.move(state_.live.velocity_);
    if((shape.getGlobalBounds().top <  0 || shape.getGlobalBounds().top > 200/*screen.y*/ )&& !state_.live.enemy_) {
        onScreen_ = false;
    }

    if(!onScreen_) {
        inUse = false;
    }
}
void BulletPool::create(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, sf::Vector2f vel) {

    assert(firstAvailable_ != NULL);

    Bullet* newBullet = firstAvailable_;
    firstAvailable_ = newBullet->getNext();
    newBullet = new Bullet(pos,color,bullet_radius,enemy,vel);

    // Find an available particle.
    /*for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {

        if (!bullets_[i].inUse()) {

            bullets_[i].init(pos,color,bullet_radius,enemy,vel);
            return;
        }
    }*/
}

void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow window) { //initializing argument 1 of 'void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow)'
    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        if (!bullets_[i].inUse) {
          // Add this particle to the front of the list.
          bullets_[i].setNext(firstAvailable_);
          firstAvailable_ = &bullets_[i];
        } else {
            window.draw(bullets_[i].shape);
        }
    }
}
Enemy::~Enemy() {};
RedShip::RedShip(sf::Vector2f pos,float side_ln) {
    movement = 10;
    shape.setPointCount(6);
    shape.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(side_ln/2, 0));
    shape.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(side_ln*3/8,side_ln*3/8));
    shape.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(0,side_ln*1/8));
    shape.setPoint(3, sf::Vector2f(side_ln/2,side_ln));
    shape.setPoint(4, sf::Vector2f(side_ln,side_ln*1/8));
    shape.setPoint(5, sf::Vector2f(side_ln*5/8,side_ln*3/8));
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    shape.setOutlineThickness(5);
    shape.setOrigin(side_ln/2, sqrt((3*side_ln*side_ln)/4));
    shape.setPosition(pos);
}

void RedShip::update(float base_time, BulletPool bullets) {
    if(movement > 1) {
        shape.move(3,1.5);
        movement--;
    }
    else if(movement < -1) {
        shape.move(-3,1.5);
        movement++;
    }
    else if(movement == -1)
        movement = 30;
    else
        movement = -30;

    if(fmod(base_time,20)==0) {
    bullets.create({shape.getPosition().x, shape.getPosition().y + shape.getLocalBounds().height/2}, sf::Color::Red, 4,true, {0,6});
    }
}


GreenShip::GreenShip(sf::Vector2f pos, float side_ln) {
    movement={};
    shape.setPointCount(8);
    shape.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
    shape.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(0,side_ln*2/3));
    shape.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(side_ln/2,side_ln));
    shape.setPoint(3, sf::Vector2f(side_ln,side_ln*2/3));
    shape.setPoint(4, sf::Vector2f(side_ln,0));
    shape.setPoint(5, sf::Vector2f(side_ln*3/4,side_ln/2));
    shape.setPoint(6, sf::Vector2f(side_ln/2,side_ln*3/8));
    shape.setPoint(7, sf::Vector2f(side_ln*1/4,side_ln/2));
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Green);
    shape.setOutlineThickness(5);
    shape.setOrigin(side_ln/2, sqrt((3*side_ln*side_ln)/4));
    shape.setPosition(pos);
}

void GreenShip::update(float base_time,BulletPool bullets) {

    shape.move(0,1);

    if(fmod(base_time,60)==0) {
    //bullets.push_back(new Bullet({shape.getPosition().x, shape.getPosition().y + shape.getLocalBounds().height/2 + 4}, sf::Color::Green, 4,true, 2));
    }
}

class Core {
public:
    const float core_velocity{5};
    int bullet_count{0};

    sf::ConvexShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;

    Core(float sX, float sY, float scale) {
        shape.setPointCount(12);
        shape.setPoint(0,{scale/2,0});
        shape.setPoint(1,{scale*7/16,scale*2/16});
        shape.setPoint(2,{scale*6/16,scale*4/16});
        shape.setPoint(3,{scale*5/16,scale*7/16+scale/3});
        shape.setPoint(4,{0,scale*10/16+scale/2});
        shape.setPoint(5,{0,scale*13/16+scale/3});
        shape.setPoint(6,{scale*8/16,scale*10/16+scale/3});
        shape.setPoint(7,{scale,scale*13/16+scale/3});
        shape.setPoint(8,{scale,scale*10/16+scale/2});
        shape.setPoint(9,{scale*11/16,scale*7/16+scale/3});
        shape.setPoint(10,{scale*10/16,scale*4/16});
        shape.setPoint(11,{scale*9/16,scale*2/16});
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
        shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
        shape.setOutlineThickness(7);
        shape.setOrigin(scale/2, scale/2);
        shape.setPosition(sX, sY);
    }

    void update() {

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            velocity.x = -core_velocity;
        else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            velocity.x = core_velocity;
        else
            velocity.x = 0;

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            velocity.y = -core_velocity;
        else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            velocity.y = core_velocity;
        else
            velocity.y = 0;

        shape.move(velocity);

    }

    void fire(BulletPool bullets) {
        if(bullet_count < 3) {
            bullets.create({shape.getPosition().x, shape.getPosition().y-shape.getLocalBounds().height/2 -1}, sf::Color::White, 6,false,{0,-8});
            bullet_count++;
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const sf::Vector2f res{480,640};
    printf("Religion ist das Opium des Volkes.\n                -Marx\n");
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(res.x,res.y), "Brick Breaker", sf::Style::None);

    float base_time{0};
    Core core(res.x / 2, res.y /2 + 200, 64);
    GreenShip ship({res.x/2,50},50);
    GreenShip ship1({res.x/2+100,50},50);
    BulletPool bullets;
    //std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
                {

                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                        window.close();
                        break;

                    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                        switch (event.key.code) {

                            case sf::Keyboard::Q:
                                core.fire(bullets);
                                break;

                            case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                                window.close();
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
        }
        }

        if(base_time<3600)
            base_time++;
        else
            base_time=0;

        window.clear();
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);

        core.update();
        window.draw(core.shape);

        ship.update(base_time,bullets);
        window.draw(ship.shape);

        ship1.update(base_time,bullets);
        window.draw(ship1.shape);

        bullets.update(window); //use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'

        /*for(auto& b : bullets) {
            if(!b->onScreen) {
                core.bullet_count--;
            }
            else {
                window.draw(b->shape);
                b->update(res,base_time,bullets);
            }
        }*/
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

enemies.hpp (no errors in this one)

```
#ifndef ENEMIES_HPP
#define ENEMIES_HPP

class Enemy{
public:
    sf::ConvexShape shape;
    int movement;
    virtual void update(float base_time, BulletPool bullets) = 0;
    virtual ~Enemy() = 0;
};



class RedShip: public Enemy{
public:
    RedShip(sf::Vector2f pos, float side_ln);
    void update(float base_time, BulletPool bullets);
};

class GreenShip: public Enemy{
public:
    GreenShip(sf::Vector2f pos, float side_ln);
    void update(float base_time, BulletPool bullets);
};



#endif
```

bullets.hpp

```
#ifndef BULLETS_HPP
#define BULLETS_HPP

class Bullet{ //Bullet::Bullet(Bullet&&)// CANT UNDERSTAND WHY THIS POPS UP
public:
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    Bullet(); //unless i add this constructor it gives the error below↓
    Bullet* getNext() const { return state_.next_; }
    void setNext(Bullet* next) { state_.next_ = next; }
    Bullet(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, sf::Vector2f vel); //Bullet::Bullet(sf::Vector2f, sf::Color, float, bool, float, float)
    void update(sf::Vector2f screen);
    bool inUse;

private:
    bool onScreen_=true;
    union { //'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
        struct {
        bool enemy_;
        sf::Vector2f velocity_;
        } live; //union member 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::live' with non-trivial 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::<constructor>()'

        Bullet *next_;

    } state_;
};

class BulletPool{
public:
    BulletPool();
    void create(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, sf::Vector2f vel);
    void update(sf::RenderWindow window);

private:
  static const int POOL_SIZE = 100;
  Bullet bullets_[POOL_SIZE];
  Bullet* firstAvailable_;
};

#endif
```

All errors as they are shown in eclipse:

```
[solved]use of deleted function 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()'

initializing argument 1 of 'void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow)'

use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'

'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

union member 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::live' with non-trivial 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::<constructor>()'
```

compiler log(mingw g++):

```
10:22:57 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Black Lambda ****
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++0x -DSFML_STATIC -D__GX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_0X__ -D_cplusplus=201103L "-IC:\\SFML-2.3.2\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
..\main.cpp: In constructor 'Bullet::Bullet(sf::Vector2f, sf::Color, float, bool, sf::Vector2f)':
..\main.cpp:24:100: error: use of deleted function 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()'
 Bullet::Bullet(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, sf::Vector2f vel) {
                                                                                                    ^
In file included from ..\main.cpp:6:0:
..\bullets.hpp:16:8: note: 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  union {
        ^
..\bullets.hpp:20:5: error: union member 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::live' with non-trivial 'Bullet::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::<constructor>()'
   } live;
     ^
..\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
..\main.cpp:261:30: error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'
         bullets.update(window);
                              ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:47:0,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp:44:25: note: 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderWindow : public Window, public RenderTarget
                         ^
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp:44:25: error: use of deleted function 'sf::Window::Window(const sf::Window&)'
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window.hpp:42:0,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window/Window.hpp:57:23: note: 'sf::Window::Window(const sf::Window&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class SFML_WINDOW_API Window : GlResource, NonCopyable
                       ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/FileInputStream.hpp:34:0,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System.hpp:35,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:67:5: error: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&)' is private
     NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&);
     ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window.hpp:42:0,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window/Window.hpp:57:23: error: within this context
 class SFML_WINDOW_API Window : GlResource, NonCopyable
                       ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:47:0,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp:44:25: error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderTarget::RenderTarget(const sf::RenderTarget&)'
 class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderWindow : public Window, public RenderTarget
                         ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:45:0,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp:51:25: note: 'sf::RenderTarget::RenderTarget(const sf::RenderTarget&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderTarget : NonCopyable
                         ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/FileInputStream.hpp:34:0,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System.hpp:35,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Window.hpp:32,
                 from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:32,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp:67:5: error: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const sf::NonCopyable&)' is private
     NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&);
     ^
In file included from C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:45:0,
                 from ..\main.cpp:1:
C:\SFML-2.3.2\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp:51:25: error: within this context
 class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderTarget : NonCopyable
                         ^
..\main.cpp:64:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow)'
 void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow window) {
      ^

10:22:59 Build Finished (took 1s.427ms)
```

I am just trying to learn c++ so
ANY HELP or critism IS APPRECIATED, THANKS!

**EDIT**
thanks a lot for all the help. i figured all of the problems out.
The problem with BulletPool::update was that the renderwindow object was being passed without a reference causing the function to copy the window and thus not render.

Comment: `sf::Vector2f` is not a *pod*, So your `union` is an [Unrestricted_union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions).

Comment: @RichardDally i am trying to setup the union such that it stores the values of the bullet object when it is in use and the value of the next pointer when its not.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks a lot i didnt know the thing with pods

Comment: This is the [shortest code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem?

Comment: im sorry for bothering your eyes with text, i guess. I just didn't know where the problem was. I am a new learner sorry for all the problems i have caused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because, as the message is saying, you have a `union` member (your anonymous `struct`) that has a member (`velocity_`) without a default constructor (or with a non-trivial one,) which makes the whole struct a non-POD (not a plain old datatype), which in turn prevents the compiler from generating default methods for it.

The relevant rule here, to put it simply, is that if you have something in your `union` (directly in the union or somewhere in the contained structs or classes) that has a non-trivial constructor (the `sf::Vector2f` in this case) then *you need to write a default constructor for the union* (and probably the related methods, e.g. destructor, copy ctor, etc.)

And if you think about it, this is rational. If you have complex things in your union, then the compiler needs to know in what state does the instances of that union begin their life.

Basically, the solution comes down to naming your union type, and then writing a simple (even empty) default constructor for it. Although you probably want to initialize the `next_` pointer to `nullptr` or `this+1` or something. You might need to write or at least specify other basic methods.

Comment: Well thanks a lot that fixed the union problem but the errors in the main.cpp still exist? I dont understand why? I edited the source so it took 2 floats instead of sf::Vector2f but still there are errors? and also in the bullets.hpp file unless i add an empty constructor first the main constructor gives errors.

Comment: alright i figured it out. The problem was probably beacuse of the struct in the class the bullet object was being assigned a default constructor which in turn caused my constructor to not function